# Error compiling tensorflow from source

Tags: gcc, tensorflow, bazel

After configuring tensorflow i run :

```
$ bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

and I get :

> WARNING: /home/f390/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1634:1: in includes attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:framework_headers_lib: '../../external/nsync/public' resolves to 'external/nsync/public' not below the relative path of its package 'tensorflow/core'. This will be an error in the future. Since this rule was created by the macro 'cc_header_only_library', the error might have been caused by the macro implementation in /home/f390/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:911:30
>   WARNING: /home/f390/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD:15:1: in py_library rule //tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn: target '//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn' depends on deprecated target '//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:exporter': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately.
>   WARNING: /home/f390/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD:15:1: in py_library rule //tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn: target '//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn' depends on deprecated target '//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:gc': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately.
>   INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (0 packages loaded).
>   INFO: Found 1 target...
>   ERROR: /home/f390/.cache/bazel/_bazel_f390/1eade5de15db7071cc11285c76340430/external/protobuf_archive/BUILD:263:1: C++ compilation of rule '@protobuf_archive//:js_embed' failed (Exit 127)
>   /usr/bin/env: 'python\r': No such file or directory
>   Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
>   Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
>   INFO: Elapsed time: 7.493s, Critical Path: 0.18s
>   FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

How to fix this error?

Comment: Did you run `./configure` before that?

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you building? Does it also happen at HEAD?
 What version of bazel do you use?

Comment: yes I did ./configure.
I am trying to build branch r1.3

Answer (score 0):

This problem also appear during building tensorflow 2 for python3. According to [this issue](http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15618), the problem is that bazel have python2 as dependency. The easiest way to fix it is just install python2 on your machine with apt (worked for me):

`sudo apt install python`

Or if you do not want install extra package you can try special flag for bazel build as suggested in [this answer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10289#issuecomment-492102920):

'--noincompatible_strict_action_env'